# Can I get an location arrow, reload, search buttons from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I would like to use some standard icons in my app for a custom view I am creating. I only need the image with the alpha. How can I get those without redesigning them and preferably not having to download them from the web?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this the free option may have all you need if not you can obtain the other source http://www.glyphish.com you can get hold of the images from the sdk however not sure you are allowed...

Or even better use this it should have what you need in psd http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-6-gui-psd-iphone-5/